# Connect oracle from nodejs

Tags: sql, oracle, node.js, oracle11g

Last few weeks I had been trying to connect oracle db from my nodejs code. What I found so far are 2 main libraries such as https://github.com/mariano/node-db-oracle which is out of date (last update was year ago) and second one is https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-oracle which is really up to date, however I didn't manage to connect oracle with any of those modules.

Mayor issue that npm install oracle //pr db-oracle fails due to

```
../src/connection.h:10:18: fatal error: occi.h: No such file or directory
```

I tried to clone the code and perform local install and then copy entire module under my project, install wen well, but when I place module under my project I run into this error

```
    module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/oracle_bindings'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/node-test/node_modules/db-oracle/db-oracle.js:18:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I had been follow installation procedure for both drivers and had been setup variables
like this (/var/environment)

```
OCI_HOME=/opt/instantclient_12_1
OCI_VERSION=12
OCI_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include
OCI_LIB_DIR=/opt/instantclient_12_1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib
```

I used ubuntu 12.04, and node version is v0.10.18
here is my sample nodejs test file:

```
var oracle = require('oracle');


new oracle.Database({
    hostname: 'myserver.com',
    port: 1521,
    user: 'myuser',
    password: 'mypass',
    database: 'XE'
}).connect(function(error) {
    if (error) {
        return console.log("CONNECTION ERROR: " + error);
    }
    this.query("select * FROM `store`").execute(function(error, rows) {
        if (error) {
            return console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
        }
        console.log(rows.length + ' ROWS');
    });
});
```

any additional hint would be nice. I tried noradle (https://github.com/kaven276/noradle) that one seems to be to heavy for my purpose.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post... just wanted to mention a sure way for nodejs to communicate to oracle without extra modules.

Set up oracle so it can create and receive http requests.  There are a few ways to do this:

The easiest is to turn on the epg gateway:

- http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_epg_10gR2.php

Also you can setup modplsq:

- http://www.comp.dit.ie/btierney/oracle11gdoc/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_web.htm

or the Apex listener:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex-listener/overview/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnpt

Then in node js do a standard http.get:

```
http.get("http://localhost/accessor/myschema.my_procedure?x=1&y=2", function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
   console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
```

});

Whichever approach...secure oracle so that it will only respond to the ip address of the nodejs server.   So if running on localhost:

```
if owa_util.get_cgi_env('REMOTE_ADDR') = '127.0.0.1' then 
   --ok
else
   -- fail
end if;
```

Also block calls to every other package and procedure. There are few ways to do this depending on the path you take.

Make sure you do this at a minimum:

- create a white list of items which can be called from the web
- require that all urls contain the schema name such as:  myuser.myprocedure
- make sure the first portion of the url (up to the query path) contains a-z 0-9 only
- really a good white list will take care of most of these items

There you have it...no need to worry if a module will break or stop working with the next release.

AND...you can easily communicate from Oracle to Node use:

- apex_web_service.make_rest_request
- utl_http

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the Instant Client as described [here](https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-oracle#install)? If I'm reading this correctly, you need the Basic (or Basic Lite) and SDK Instant Client packages. The SDK package might have the header file you're having trouble with.

Side note: in my experience, you don't always need to add Instant Client to `PATH`; you can usually get away with just making sure your executable can find it (which often means just dropping it in the same directory).

Comment: actually I recently manage to connect to Oracle. PATHs were problems.

Comment: @vaske I try to avoid putting Oracle stuff on my path. It tends to become a problem when a different project needs a different client. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Set the oracle client path in the command prompt like below before starting the Node application

Set PATH=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\instantclient_12_1;%PATH%

I had the above problem , this resolved mine and I am now able to connect to oracle .

But the one problem I am still facing is executing the select statement .It always returns error. I am able to execute SP, create statements and everything else without error . I am stuck here and sort of disappointed .

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Set PATH puts the string you specified at the beginning of your Path environment variable. I entered the instant client folder path at the beginning.

> C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\instantclient_12_1;

It fixed the oracle binding error, but the queries wouldn't work. Then, I added the vc11 folder path BEFORE the instant client path, so it looks like this :

> C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\instantclient_12_1\vc11;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\instantclient_12_1;

Now my queries work!