# Oracle with node-oracle: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804

Tags: node.js, oracle

I'm trying to use [node-oracle](https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle) to connect to a Oracle 11g database in UNIX. I can connect fine to the database using TOAD, but now I want to do application queries and this is what I did:

NodeJS code:

```
var oracle = require('oracle');

var connectData = {
  hostname: "host.com",
  port: 1521,
  database: "DB0000",
  user: "me",
  password: "password"
}

oracle.connect(connectData, function(err, connection) {
  if (err) { console.log("Error connecting to db:", err); return; }

  connection.execute("SELECT systimestamp FROM dual", [], function(err, results) {
    if (err) { console.log("Error executing query:", err); return; }

    console.log(results);
    connection.close();
  });
});
```

Then I this command on the unix box:

```
sh-3.2$ OCI_LIB_DIR= /oracle/client/v11.2.0.2-64bit/client_1/lib/ OCI_INCLUDE_DIR=/client/v11.2.0.2-64bit/client_1/rdbms/public/ OCI_HOME=/oracle/clien
t/v11.2.0.2-64bit/client_1/ NLS_LANG=.UTF8 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/client/v11.2.0.2-64bit/client_1/lib/ /bin/node app.js
```

I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'oracle::occi::SQLException'
  what():  Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804
```

Some notes:

- I haven't set up env variables properly yet, this was my first test, thus the long `node` command.
- the paths are similar to those described but I removed the prefixes which would tie this to my company

I've looked around the web and a lot of people point this to a poorly configured `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. If I `ls` that folder I get:

```
acfslib.pm          libclient11.a      libgnsjni11.so     libmm.a        libntcpaio11.so        liboraz.a          libsql11.a          naect_std.o.dbl             sscoreed.o
acfsroot.pl         libclntsh.so       libhasgen11.so     libn11.a       libntcps11.a           liborion11.a       libsqlplus.a        naedhs.o                    stubs
acfstoolsdriver.sh  libclntsh.so.10.1  libheteroxa11.so   libnbeq11.a    libntcps11_std.a.dbl   libowm2.so         libsqlplus.so       naeet.o                     sysliblist
activation.jar      libclntsh.so.11.1  libimf.a           libncrypt11.a  libntns11.a            libplc11.a         libsqora.so.11.1    naeet_std.o.dbl             transx.zip
classgen.jar        libclntst11.a      libintlc.so.5      libnhost11.a   libnus11.a             libplc11_pic.a     libsrvm11.so        nautab.o                    xmlcomp2.jar
clntsh.map          libclsra11.so      libipgo.a          libnjni11.so   libnzjs11.a            libplp11.a         libsrvmhas11.so     nautab_std.o.dbl            xmlcomp.jar
facility.lis        libcommon11.a      libipp_bz2.a       libnl11.a      libocci11.a            libplp11_pic.a     libsrvmocr11.so     nigcon.o                    xml.jar
jcr-1.0.jar         libcore11.a        libippcore.a       libnldap11.a   libocci.so             libpls11.a         libsvml.a           nigtab.o                    xmlmesg.jar
jdev-rt.zip         libcorejava.so     libippdcemerged.a  libnls11.a     libocci.so.11.1        libpls11_pic.a     libuini11.so        nnfgt.o                     xmlparserv2.jar
lclasses12.zip      libcxaguard.so.5   libippdcmerged.a   libnnet11.a    libocijdbc11.so        libpsa11.a         libunls11.a         ntcontab.o                  xmlparserv2_jaxp_services.jar
lclasses14.zip      libdbcfg11.so      libippsemerged.a   libnnetd11.a   libocr11.so            librdjni11.so      libvsn11.a          ojcr.jar                    xmlparserv2_sans_jaxp_services.jar
ldflags             libeons.so         libippsmerged.a    libnnz11.a     libocrb11.so           libskgxn2.so       libvsn11_std.a.dbl  oraclexsql.jar              xschema.jar
ldflagsO            libexpat.a         libipp_z.a         libnnz11.so    libocrutl11.so         libskgxp11.so      libwwg.a            osds_acfslib.pm             xsqlserializers.jar
libagent11.a        libexpat.la        libirc.a           libnoname11.a  liboevm.a              libskgxpcompat.so  libxdb.so           osds_acfsroot.pm            xsu12.jar
libagfw11.so        libexpat.so        libldapclnt11.a    libnque11.so   libons.so              libskgxpd.so       libxml11.a          osds_unix_linux_acfslib.pm
libagtsh.so         libexpat.so.1      libldapjclnt11.a   libnro11.a     libonsx.so             libskgxpg.so       libzt11.a           osntabst.o
libagtsh.so.1.0     libexpat.so.1.5.2  libldapjclnt11.so  libnsgr11.a    liborabz2.a            libskgxpr.so       libztkg11.a         s0main.o
libasmclntsh11.so   libgeneric11.a     liblxled.a         libnsslb11.a   liborasdkbase.so.11.1  libslax11.a        mail.jar            schagent.jar
libcell11.so        libgns11.so        liblzopro.a        libntcp11.a    liborasdk.so.11.1      libsnls11.a        naect.o             scorept.o
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've looked at these question, but although similar I couldn't troubleshoot my problem with them:

- [Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560925/error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01019)
- [Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837811/error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01804)

Cheers.

Comment: Please refer to that error:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837811/error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01804

Comment: And the parameters you should set are ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID usually (ORACLE HOME is to the base oracle directory)

Comment: If you want to try a different approach, I posted a comment on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696000/connect-oracle-from-nodejs showing another way for nodejs->oracle communication.

Comment: I will try the `ORACLE_HOME` and `SID` and let you know. Thanks @BrianMcGinity for the added suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @evenro, I went back to look at [Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837811/error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01804) and tried setting the `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable.

It worked, but then I started checking which variables I really needed, so in the end I only used:

- ORACLE_HOME: pointing at the oracle client basedir
- LD_LIBRARY_PATH: point at the lib folder inside the client

This is how it worked in the end:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/somefolder/oracle/client/v11.2.0.2-64bit/client_1/ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/somefolder/oracle/client/v11.2.0.2-64bit/client_1/lib/ node app.js
```

Thank you again for all the help in the comments, much appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem earlier but it turned out I missed the "libociei.so". Once I put it in a directory that can be accessed by loader (in my case, /usr/lib), It worked fine, I stopped seeing the message "Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804".

Answer (score 2):

In my case I solved it like this for *python*

I solved this by simply zipping the files properly with the symbolic links

First I created three symbolic links :

`ln -s ./lib/libaio.so.1.0.1 ./lib/libaio.so.1`

`ln -s ./lib/libaio.so.1.0.1 ./lib/libaio.so`

`ln -s ./lib/libaio.so.1.0.1 ./libaio.so.1.0.1`

`ln -s ./lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 ./lib/libclntsh.so`

then I was zipping it incorrectly I did it like this:

`zip --symlinks -r9 ~/lamda.zip *`

It worked! properly then.Hope it helps somebody.