# "Warning: oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed" and "Warning: oci_connect(): Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804"

Tags: php, oracle, apache, redhat, oci8

I'm new to PHP and Oracle. I'm trying to make a connection between my application in PHP and an Oracle DataBase. I'm using:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
PHP 5.4.16 
Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)

In order to do that I installed Oracle Client and oci8, but I am having these:

**Warning: oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries in /var/www/html/TTS/Portal/Recursos/php/login/Login.php on line 7**

**Warning: oci_connect(): Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804 in /var/www/html/TTS/Portal/Recursos/php/login/Login.php on line 7**

Line 7 has:

**$Conexion=oci_connect('user', 'pass','Ipaddress/DBname');**

I read that it could a problem with environment variables

I have in /root/.bash_profile, the following text:

**export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64**
**export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib**
**export NLS_LANG=American_America.UTF8**

**PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/bin**

**export PATH**

In /etc/sysconfig/httpd, I have:

**LANG=C**
**ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64**
**LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib**
**NLS_LANG=American_America.UTF8**
**export ORACLE_HOME**
**export LD_LIBRARY_PATH**
**export NLS_LANG**

phpinfo() shows me the following:
[Apache environment and Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCVx9.jpg)
[PHP variables and Oci8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwPJr.jpg)

I don't know how to fix the problems, I'd appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: `failure to initialize timezone information
Cause:   The timezone information file was not properly read.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060594/oracle-with-node-oracle-error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01804

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't set correctly, try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib`