# Connecting to Oracle RDS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle using AWS lambda and python.

These are the step I followed. (Everything has done EC2 instance)

1. Downloaded the instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip and
   instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
2. Created this folder structure `~/lambda/lib/`
3. Extracted the `zip` files in the `~/lambda/lib/`
4. copied the `libaio.so.1.0.1` from `/lib64/` into `~/lambda/lib/`
5. Created symbolic link of `libaio.so.1.0.1` as `libaio.so` in `~/lambda`
6. using pip installed `cx_Oracle` in `~/lambda`
7. written below `index.py` script in `~lambda`

`

```
import cx_Oracle

def handler(event, context):
    message = ""
    cursor = None
    connection = None    
    try:
        connection = cx_Oracle.connect("USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DOMAIN/orcl")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""QUERY""")
    except Exception as e:
        message += " {Error in connection} " + str(e)
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if connection:
            connection.close()
    return {'message' : message}
```

`

8. Then zipped it using `zip -r9 ~/upload.zip *`

After running the code on AWS lambda it gives the following error.

`Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804`

I tried setting ENV ORACLE_HOME=/var/task and /var/task/lib but did not worked

I looked below answers but did not find help yet

[Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560925/error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01019)

[Oracle with node-oracle: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060594/oracle-with-node-oracle-error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01804)

Comment: Also related; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837811/error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01804

Comment: The answers there are not descriptive and they don't help in solving the problem. Is this because of some VPC issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by simply zipping the files properly with the symbolic links

First I created three symbolic links (with respect to above dir structure):

`ln -s ./lib/libaio.so.1.0.1 ./lib/libaio.so.1`

`ln -s ./lib/libaio.so.1.0.1 ./lib/libaio.so`

`ln -s ./lib/libaio.so.1.0.1 ./libaio.so.1.0.1`

`ln -s ./lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 ./lib/libclntsh.so`

then i was zipping it incorretly I did it like this:

`zip --symlinks -r9 ~/lamda.zip *`

it worked! properly then.Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: I had to provide the complete path /var/task/lib/libaio.so.1.0.1 and then it worked

Comment: Thank you! I tried many approaches to this, but yours worked like a charm. No need to set env vars or fiddle with host files.

Answer (score 4):

This post was much helpful for me to use cx_Oracle using Lambda functions. It worked as expected. Thanks for creating this post @Sayed Zainul Abideen

But i got another error from lambda stating ***'cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-24454: client host name is not set'***

I got it resolved by adding the below lines in my python code:

```
import os

with open('/tmp/HOSTALIASES', 'w') as hosts_file:
    hosts_file.write('{} localhost\n'.format(os.uname()[1]))
```

After which i added below ENVIRONMENTAL VARIABLE to my Lambda function:

```
HOSTALIASES = /tmp/HOSTALIASES
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Please add comments if any issues relating to cx_Oracle. I would be happy to help as i struggled a lot to fix this.

Comment: Thanks this did help. I can't help but feel there must be a better way, but this worked.

Comment: I am using a similar setup, but with nodejs lambda using oracledb_for_lambda. It always throws ORA-21561: OID generation failed. The lambda functions are within a VPC and connects over to the on-prem oracle database(RAC Cluster). Connectivity is verified though.