# Error Connecting to Oracle with Lambda using VPC

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am trying to connect to oracle db by using lambda. 
I have installed all the dependency in lib and made a zip container

Dir structure:
`

```
root/
    lib/(client lib)
    index.py
    cx_oracle.so*
```

`

```
import cx_Oracle

def handler(event, context):
    message = ""
    cursor = None
    connection = None    
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DOMAIN/orcl")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""QUERY""")
    message += " {Error in connection} " + str(e)
    if cursor:
        cursor.close()
    if connection:
        connection.close()
    return {'message' : message}
```

Error are:

libaio.so and libclntsh.so library not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to create symbolic links without the version no.

refer to this [Connecting to Oracle RDS using AWS Lambda using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937833/connecting-to-oracle-rds-using-aws-lambda-using-python/46954434#46954434)