# Using cx_Oracle and Lambda Layer, getting AWS Lambda Error: error while trying to retrieve text for error ora-01804

Tags: python, aws-lambda, cx-oracle, oracleclient, aws-lambda-layers

I created two separate Lambda layers by adding **cx_Oracle_lambda_layer.zip** and **Oracle_Instant_client_lambda_layer.zip** from this [github solution](https://github.com/prabhakarniraula/LambdaLayersPython).

After using those Lambda layers, in the Lambda function, I can import cx_Oracle successfully, but getting the following error while creating a connection to an Oracle DB.

[image: Image of error]

The same works successfully from a Windows machine and I can fetch and push data, but facing this problem in AWS Lambda.

I am okay to create a deployment package for the same if that is an easy way out, but after going through a couple of SO Q/As I found it a little difficult to figure out the exact steps.

Went through [this SO Q and A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937833/connecting-to-oracle-rds/46954434#46954434) written by the same person for building a deployment package but I am not very clear of few steps in between.

Any help shall be greatly acknowledged.